# ElasticSearch multiple values as input ( regex as well ) to match (should ) in multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Case:

```
  Example Documents :
 {owner:name1 , maintainer:name23, someotherfield:something },
{ owner:name2 , maintainer:name355,  someotherfield:something }

Input : [ name1 , name2 ,s.* ]

Query : {
 "should": [
               {
                 "terms": {
                  "owner": [ name1 , name2 ,something ]
                 }

              },{
                 "terms": {
                   "maintainer":  [ name1 , name2 ,something ]
                 }
               },{

                 "terms": {
                   "someotherfield": [ name1 , name2 ,ssomething ]
                 }
               }
               }

                ]
}
```

The above query works as expected and will match both documents. 
but when i change to :

```
   Query : {
 "should": [
               {
                 "terms": {
                  "owner": [ name.* , name.* ,some.* ]
                 }

              },{
                 "terms": {
                   "maintainer":  [ name.*, name.* ,some.* ]
                 }
               },{

                 "terms": {
                   "someotherfield":  [ name.*, name.* ,some.* ]
                 }
               }
               }

                ]
}
```

it fails and wont match anything!

i am tring to make a query that given the above input it SHOULD match ANY of the input fields to ANY of the search fields . It works perfectly with exact matches (name1 ,name2) but it fails when using regex ( name3.*) 
The desired behaviour is match any of the input values  to any of the fields in the documents even if the input has regex like .*value ( ends ) .*value.* (contains) value.* (ends) and return all the documents that even one match was found

Answer (score 0):

For any future reads this gets solved by using regex search and implementing the search strings as

- exact : /string1|string2|string3/
- contains: /.*string1.*|.*string2.*|.*string3.*/
- starts : /string1.*|string2.*|string3.*/

elastic search treats | as OR so you go full regex to achieve the desired behaviour

also an normalizer was needed in order to have a " full text " index